# Get a set of 2d list in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, set

I have a `list` like follows:

```
t=[[1, 7], [3, 7], [1, 7], [5, 8], [3, 7]]
```

I need to get a `set` out of this so the output would be like:

```
t=[[1, 7], [3, 7], [5, 8]]
```

I tried to use `t = set(t)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Convert the items to tuple and pass them to `OrderedDict.fromkeys` and then finally convert the tuple keys to list again. (If order matters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not care about the order, you can first convert the inner `lists` to `tuples` using `map()` function, and then convert them to `set` and then back to `list` .

Example -

```
>>> t=[[1, 7], [3, 7], [1, 7], [5, 8], [3, 7]]
>>> t = list(set(map(tuple,t)))
>>> t
[(3, 7), (5, 8), (1, 7)]
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, would advice you to accept answers , the best one you think, would help people who have similar questions and the community as whole.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, `lists` are mutable and thus one cannot make a `set` out of them as they might change. Thus you want to use `tuples` which are immutable. Thus you can use:

```
list(set([tuple(ti) for ti in t]))
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you do care about order:

```
def func(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        item = tuple(item)
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

Or you simply subclass list and override append so no duplicates can be added in the first place:

```
class T(list):
    def append(self, item):
        if item not in self:
            list.append(self, item)
```

Which would be used like this:

```
>>> t = T([[1, 7], [3, 7], [5, 8]])
>>> t
[[1, 7], [3, 7], [5, 8]]
>>> t.append([1, 7])
>>> t
[[1, 7], [3, 7], [5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sets can only contain immutable elements. `list` is mutable type, you need to convert items to immutable type, e.g. `tuple`:

```
set(map(tuple, t))
```