# connect python 2d set in between x.end to y.start

Tags: python, sorting, set

I have 2D set in python as follows.

```
{(59, 122),
 (107, 59),
 (122, 928),
 (172, 646),
 (254, 547),
 (265, 840),
 (547, 753),
 (646, 265),
 (717, 172),
 (753, 107),
 (840, 254),
 (928, 717)}
```

I want to reorder this set as follows,

```
{(59, 122),
 (122, 928),
 (928, 717),
 (717, 172),
 (172, 646),
 (646, 265),
 (265, 840),
 (840, 254),
 (254, 547),
 (547, 753),
 (753, 107),
 (107, 59)}
```

What I wanted is just connect the set to y.end == x.start(next x)
What I have in mind is compare every values using for loop, but it is really straight-forward.
Is there any better and simple code? thank you.

Comment: From docs: [`A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements.`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). You might want to use `list` or `tuple` here.

Comment: Thank you, and I think I found solution in user1602492's answer in here : 
Edit : It is not correct in my situation, sorry... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053385/get-a-set-of-2d-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph problem; what you have is an edge list, and you're trying to find the circuit in the graph, in order.

One solution is to read up on any convenient graph package, such as `networkx`, and use those facilities.  There will be a lot of set-up, but the execution will be simple from there.

Another is to build your own.  Since all of these edges are nicely directed, you can do it with a dict.  Start by turning this into a dict.

```
edge_list = {x:y for x, y in 2Dset}
```

Now, simply walk through the list from your start node, adding each edge in order:

```
circuit = []
x = 59
y = None

while y != 59:
    y = edge_list[x]
    circuit.append( (x, y) )
    x = y

for edge in circuit:
    print(edge)
```

Result:

```
{59: 122, 646: 265, 717: 172, 254: 547, 122: 928, 265: 840, 753: 107, 928: 717, 172: 646, 840: 254, 107: 59, 547: 753}
(59, 122)
(122, 928)
(928, 717)
(717, 172)
(172, 646)
(646, 265)
(265, 840)
(840, 254)
(254, 547)
(547, 753)
(753, 107)
(107, 59)
```

Comment: Thank you, and if we do not consider the order of the start point, x might be, x = list(edge_list.keys())[0]